# Jquery to native js

Tags: javascript, jquery, native

есть JQ код:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.textsize = function(kompressor, options) {
    var compressor = kompressor || 1,
      settings = $.extend({
        'minFontSize': Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
        'maxFontSize': Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
      }, options);
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var resizer = function() {
        $this.css('font-size', Math.max(Math.min($this.width() / (compressor * 5), parseFloat(settings.maxFontSize)), parseFloat(settings.minFontSize)));
      };
      resizer();
      $(window).on('resize.sizetext orientationchange.sizetext', resizer);
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".textsize").textsize( $('.numberin').val() );

}
);

$(document).keyup(function() {
  $(".textsize").textsize( $('.numberin').val() );

}
);
```

Помогите переработать в чистый js, либо подскажите пожалуйста ресурс где можно будет подглядывать определения и с jq на js переделывать...

Заранее спасибо большое.

Comment: Вот здесь можно смотреть, что выполняет каждая функция https://jquery.com/

Comment: В документации по jQuery смотрите что делает та или иная функция, после чего воспроизводите ту же логику на "чистом JS". Если не получается воспроизвести - берёте исходники jQuery и разбираетесь в них, в итоге что-то копируя оттуда или делая по-своему..

Comment: А, и главный вопрос: зачем вам это? Что вас не устраивает в текущем коде?

Comment: @Regent ну вообще в 2018 использовать JQ как то странно, тем более, что почти все уже есть в нативном JS`е

Comment: @lazyproger а что странного? Есть, например, старый проект, написанный в том числе и с использованием jQuery. Поддержку старых браузеров при этом никто не отменял. И вот надо мне сделать задачу по этому проекту. Что вы предлагаете в данной ситуации - отказываться от jQuery в пользу велосипедов? Или взять и перенести всё на TypeScript и React (а на это далеко не одна неделя уйдёт - где бы взять ресурсы на это...)?

Comment: @lazyproger я последние изменения в JS особо не изучал, но что-то мне кажется, что немало действий по-прежнему короче (в плане кода) выходят с использованием jQuery и другие библиотек.

Comment: @Regent Я ни в коем случае не хейтер JQ, просто в новых проектах не использую. И к счастью не фронтендер, а то от реактов голова болит. Вопрос о том где взять информацию, я постарался ответить. PS чего там только нет...

Comment: @Regent код будет юзататься на сайтах клиентов и не факт что у всех JQ подключен. понятно можно подгружать допом. но это лишний вес и скорость

Answer (score 2):

1) Собственно ресурс который начал двигать ваниль в массы [vanilla-js.com](http://vanilla-js.com/) много примеров для миграции

2) Наверное лучшая русскоязычная база знаний по js [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/)

3) Когда то давно решил воспроизвести Jquery функции, но пока руки не доходят, надеюсь время скоро появится [github.com/Dimario/miniJQ](https://github.com/Dimario/miniJQ)

Comment: Писать свой велосипед - это зачастую крайне сомнительное решение.

Comment: @Regent исключительно в научных целях! Своё ламповое всегда приятнее, особенно когда понимаешь как работает каждая строчка кода

Comment: @Regent, если свой велосипед легковесный (включает только код, который используется в каждом проекте) - эффективнее использовать его, вместо жирной жквери. Благодаря webpack'у можно удобно минифицировать и компоновать такие микро-велосипеды в один файлик. Конечно, это решение только для тех кто пишет на чистом JS, и может+хочет обходиться без некоторых библиотек общего назначения.

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас буду пробовать...)

Comment: @yar85 почему вы решили, что jQuery жирный? Да, на каких-то простеньких страничках размер библиотеки будет заметен. Но в сколько-либо серьёзных проектах, а также при текущих скоростях интернета (не говоря уж о кешировании скриптов) и мощностях устройств это не звучит как проблема. И ещё: хорошо если свои велосипеды используете только вы (хотя даже в этом случае вам придётся потратить время на разработку и отладку велосипедов), а если их придётся использовать другим разработчикам? Почему они должны разбираться в том как это использовать?

Comment: @Regent мне интереснее разработать своё JQ, чем использовать готовое JQ. Мне не интересно делать попапы.. мне интереснее разобрать в доках как работает dialog.. мне не интересно писать $.ajax, я хочу хардкор и свой класс для работы с XHR. На продакшене я не буду это использовать, но для себя, why not? А если я сделаю так, что мне понравится, то почему бы и не на прод?

Comment: @Regent *"почему вы решили, что jQuery жирный?"* - а почему такая некорректная формулировка вопроса? Решил не я, а авторы. *"...другим разработчикам? Почему они должны разбираться в том как это использовать?"* - действительно, почему? Если это ***разработчики*** (то есть, они знают JS и способны прочесть JSDoc / подсказку в редакторе с интеллисенсом), разбираться им не придется.

Comment: @lazyproger каждому - своё, это понятно. И проекты бывают разные. Но вот в чём бывают проблемы с _"мне интереснее разработать своё JQ. Мне не интересно делать попапы"_ - а клиентам неинтересно платить деньги за велосипеды, им нужно выполнять свои задачи с помощью качественно (и подешевле для них) созданных инструментов. Также другим разработчикам в команде может оказаться неинтересно (или некогда) разбираться в этом.

Comment: @Regent, *"а клиентам неинтересно платить деньги за велосипеды"* - ок, а jQuery часто продаете клиентам? И что, действительно покупают? :D

Comment: @yar85 вы вот это всерьёз про покупку jQuery? Речь идёт про приложения, сайты и другие инструменты ведения бизнеса. Клиенту нужно чтобы его интернет-магазин нормально функционировал, или чтобы он мог сформировать и отправить отчет, или ещё что. Если есть вариант сделать за 2 недели с использованием готовых инструментов или втрое дороже за 6 недель со своими велосипедами при почти одинаковом по качеству (причем ещё непонятно что выйдет лучше) результате, то зачем клиенту платить больше? А для своих личных проектов - да пожалуйста, хоть свой язык программирования можно разрабатывать...

Comment: @Regent, *"Клиенту нужно чтобы его интернет-магазин нормально функционировал"* - вот именно! Поймете о чем тут речь, когда столкнетесь с ситуацией когда клиент смотрит на увешанный либами и фреймворками сайт, и говорит "А чойта оно так долго грузится? А чойта вот этот блок на мобиле тормозит? Я такое не заказывал, исправляйте". Ну а чтобы избавиться от предрассудков про 6 недель, достаточно научиться грамотно работать со своим собственным кодом. **p.s.:** Впервые слышу о таком чуде, что заказчик оплачивает задержки в работе исполнителя `О_о` в реальном мире, ситуация... кхм, несколько иная.

Comment: @Regent, то есть, о продаже jQuery я так же несерьезно, как и ваша  смешная фраза об оплате велосипедов. Клиенту безразлично, как будет сделано - лишь бы было сделано а) качественно; б) в срок; в) с возможностью дальнейшей поддержки. Вы по-видимому упускаете тот момент, что свой готовый инструмент - такой же готовый, как и чужие. И вовсе я не говорю что каждый джуниор обязан уметь в модульность и мейнтейн. Кто-то шлепает на жквери и бутстрапе, кто-то инженерит: разные уровни квалификации (как и разные роли в команде) - подразумевают разный инструментарий и разные методики работы. Логично?

Comment: @Regent я разрабатываю исключительно свои проекты, где заказчик (тот кто платит), не будет спрашивать почему так. Если я говорю что ванила со своим велосипедом лучше, значит лучше. Вам желаю таких же заказчиков. JQ круто,  но это как школьная любовь, я давно не с ней, но забыть не могу.